# SyntaxError in with statement when opening two files

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, python-2.6

I am getting 'SyntaxError' exception raised by compiler in Python, randomly at below statement:

```
with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile, open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here inputFileName is command line parameter from my build environment and it is expected to be created and present before script is called. Below is sample code:

```
try:

with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile, open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
       print "do something"
except IOError as e: #(errno,strerror,filename):
        ## Control jumps directly to here if any of the above lines throws IOError.
        sys.stderr.write('problem with \'' + e.filename +'\'.')
        sys.stderr.write(' I/O error({0}): {1}'.format(e.errno, e.strerror) + '.' + '\n')
except:
    print "Unexpected error in generate_include_file() : ", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

I do not have any clue. please help me out.
I am using python 2.7. (python27)

Comment: Are you using python 2.6?

Comment: Multiple context expressions (separated by comma) are only allowed in Python 2.7 You can use nested with statements instead.

Comment: @Pavel I am using Python2.7

Comment: It's a little surprising that you're using Python 2.7 -- the error message you're reporting doesn't match that.  Just to rule out the possibility that the wrong Python version is being accidentally invoked, could you comment out this section of code and add `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouped `with` statements require Python 2.7 or up. For earlier versions, nest the statements:

```
with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile:
    with open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
```

The exact error message you get is strong evidence that you are running the code on Python 2.6, **not** 2.7:

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Apr 19 2012, 01:24:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile, open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile, open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

$ python2.7
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 22 2012, 06:12:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile, open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
...
```

You cannot group `with` statements with `except` handlers in *any* Python versions, you need to use a `try:` `except:` *around* the `with` statement(s) instead:

```
try:
    with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile, open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
       print "do something"
except IOError as e: #(errno,strerror,filename):
    ## Control jumps directly to here if any of the above lines throws IOError.
    sys.stderr.write("problem with '{}'. ".format(e.filename))
    sys.stderr.write(' I/O error({0}): {1}.\n'.format(e.errno, e.strerror))
except:
    print "Unexpected error in generate_include_file() : ", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

I would *not* use a blanket except myself; the blanket except catches name, memory and keyboard interrupt exceptions too, for which you usually want to *exit* your program instead.

Comment: is it for Python 2.7 as well I need to write like below:          try:
    with open(inputFileName, 'rU') as inputFile:
        with open(outputFileName,'w') as outputFile:
           print "do something"

Comment: Yes, the `try` `except` part applies to *any* python version. The `with` statement does *not* support an `except` block.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. You were pointing to missing "try:". I correct my query.

Comment: @learningstack: Your indentation in your post is out; if you still get a syntax error, you are *not* using Python 2.7. The syntax error you report is *typical* of running your code on Python 2.6.